# R - Why are the values printing to each row, instead of down one column when using 'ddply'?

Tags: r

My new data frame isn't printing properly ...
Why are the values printing to each row, instead of down one column when using 'ddply'?

```r
housing_df <- subset(housing_df,housing_df$zip5 == 98074)

#  Creating a function that calculates cost per sq foot.
sqft_cost <- function(data) 
    {(housing_df$Sale.Price)/(housing_df$square_feet_total_living)
}
# using applying function using ddply
sqft_cost1 <- ddply(housing_df, .(addr_full), .fun=sqft_cost)

names(sqft_cost1)[1] <- 'Address'
names(sqft_cost1)[2] <- 'Cost Per SQFT'
head(sqft_cost1)
```

[image: image of output]

Comment: Your function `sqft_cost` takes an argument named `data` and then ignores it. Inside the function you use `housing_df`, you should use `data` as that is the name you gave the argument.

Comment: (And this causes the problem because `ddply` breaks your data up into little pieces and passes it to `sqft_cost()`, but because you don't use `housing_df` instead of `data` argument in the function, those little pieces are ignored and the entire `housing_df` is used instead.)